# Program to make something in inactive window

Tags: python

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
import keyboard
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('f6'):
        while True:
            sleep(0.500)
            pyautogui.keyDown("a") #pressing down key 'a'
            sleep(0.500) #how ever long you want
            pyautogui.keyUp("a") #stop pressing key 'a' down
            sleep(1.000)
            pyautogui.keyDown("d") #pressing down key 'a'
            sleep(0.500) #how ever long you want
            pyautogui.keyUp("d") #stop pressing key 'a' down
            sleep(1.000)
```

I want it to do this, but in inactive window (minecraft).

I tried using ahk library, but it didn't work, I have no idea what can I use.

Comment: "it didnt work" [ask] and [mre]